# Why object is return instead of count number sequelize.js in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I cannot convince Why object is return instead of count number `sequelize.js` in NodeJS?

```
exports.getApplicationsCountForJobSeekerByUser = function (jobSeekerId, jobId) {
    return sequelize.query('select count(id) from applications where job_seeker_id = :jsId and job_id = :jId',
        { replacements: {jsId: jobSeekerId, jId: jobId}, raw: true, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT });
};
```

Please let me know how to solve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

Returned object is promise. You should do something like this:

```
getApplicationsCountForJobSeekerByUser.then(function(results){ /* do what you want with query results */}).catch(/* error handling*/)
```

Comment: I've got [object Object] result.

Comment: [object Object] is the result of .toString() before console.log(). Check this http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/raw-queries/. In Javascript almost all work with DB (I/O in general) is async. So you must use callbacks, promises, async/await, etc. to work. [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)